# Total time in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I am working on data frame. One of my column is in datetime format. Data head will look like this

```
0   2022-01-18 15:26:35
1   2022-01-18 15:26:36
2   2022-01-18 15:26:37
3   2022-01-18 15:26:38
4   2022-01-18 15:26:39
Name: filename, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I have a huge data and there is break at some point, meaning, I may not have data at night time and I dont want that time to be added in the total time. I want the total time in hours, I tried this

```
totaltime = df["filename"].sum()
totaltime
```

And I got an error, 'DatetimeArray' with dtype datetime64[ns] does not support reduction 'sum'. Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: ``2022-01-18 15:26:35 + 2022-01-18 15:26:36`` equals what? Add all the numbers? Add the (milli)seconds since [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) (then which epoch - MATLAB? Unix? ...)? Or are you looking for the difference?

Comment: What do you want the sum value to be? For example, Seconds, minutes, hours, days.

Comment: You cannot sum dates that are relative points in time. You can only sum **durations**

Comment: I want sum in hours. The data which I have shown is just 4 seconds. But I have a huge data. That's why I need like that

Comment: So you want the difference of the smallest and the largest value in hours? That's not a sum.

Comment: @Vinay what would be the expected output here?

Comment: In the data I have shown, total time is 4 seconds. In my  entire data my total time will be somewhere 100 hours, I need it

Comment: @mozway Total time = 0.001 hours

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to get in sum but I guess you want total time, it can be obtained by difference of highest timestamp,lowest timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use numpy.ptp:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(header=None, names=['filename'], sep='\s\s+')`

times = pd.to_datetime(df['filename'])

np.ptp(times)
```

Output (pd.Timedelta)

```
Timedelta('0 days 00:00:04')
```

Comment: I didn't know `numpy.ptp` nice one Scott!

Comment: I'm however quite surprised that it's less efficient than `(s.max() - s.min())` (170µs vs 90 µs). I'd have expected the other way around… Maybe the conversion to array?

Comment: @mozway try `np.ptp(times.to_numpy())`...  Let me know what you find please.

Comment: 9µs, awesome ;)

Comment: no wait, but then `s.max()-s.min()` is 3µs when s is `s = pd.to_datetime(df['filename']).to_numpy()`…

Comment: Yep, the earlier you can get to numpy the better.   But it does appear that ptp is adding overhead.  Probably should look to see what additional logic is in np.ptp.  Yeah, np.ptp is overkilll here.  Simple max minus min is best.

Comment: It wasn't, now thanks to you I know this function :)

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you want the number of hours between the max and min date:

```
t = pd.to_datetime(df['filename'])
delta = (t.max()-t.min()).total_seconds()/3600
```

output: `0.0011`

Comment: Actually I should have explained earlier. In my dataframe there is break in time.  For example, I may not have data recorded during night time and I don't want that time to include. May I know how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

```
df[['colname']] = df[['colname']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
result = (df['colname'].max() - df['colname'].min()).dt.hour
```

Comment: have you tested it?

Comment: This didn't worked actually

Answer (score 0):

Total time difference between the max and min date.

Your Data:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
temp = """
2022-01-18 15:26:35
2022-01-18 15:26:36
2022-01-18 15:26:37
2022-01-18 15:26:38
2022-01-18 15:26:39
"""

temp2 = io.StringIO(temp) 
df = pd.read_csv(temp2, sep="\s",header=None)
df["filename"] = df[0] + " " + df[1]
df = df.drop(columns=[0,1])

# Convert column to datetime datatype
df["filename"] = pd.to_datetime(df["filename"], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Parse them into strptime, so that you can subtract the dates and get the `range` between them.

```
maxTime = datetime.strptime(str(df.filename.max()), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
minTime = datetime.strptime(str(df.filename.min()), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

print(f"Range: ",maxTime-minTime)

# Range:  0:00:04
```