# Count the rows between first and second largest values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is question is similar to the one I have posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71601022/counting-number-of-rows-between-min-and-max-in-pandas/71601078?noredirect=1#comment126549760_71601078). But with a little different framework.

Let's say I have the pandas data frame:

```
d = {'a': [12, 3, 5, 2, 10, 3, 5, 4, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

I want to count a total number of rows, between the first and the second max values of column a.
In this case, it will be 3, which is the number of rows between 12 and 10. How can one do it more generically?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html):

```
In [2451]: l = df['a'].nlargest(2).index # Find indexes of top 2 largest values
In [2455]: res = abs(l[0] - l[1]) - 1 # Get the absolute diff and subtract 1

In [2456]: res
Out[2456]: 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`numpy.ptp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html):

```
out = np.ptp(df['a'].nlargest(2).index.to_numpy())-1
```

or, to work with any initial index (not only range):

```
out = np.ptp(df.reset_index()['a'].nlargest(2).index.to_numpy())-1
```

output: `3`

Comment: Great use of np.ptp . Learning something new from you. :) +1

Comment: @Mayank I learned it [no so long ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71527608/total-time-in-pandas-column/71527939#comment126420428_71527939) from ScottBoston. I already UV your answer that is obviously also an easy way to do it ;)